breakpoint in godot
hola estaba siguiendo un tutorial de godot 4 sobre barras de vida pero hubo un problema me dise que hay un "break point" y nose como solucionarlo.


func _ready():
    barra.max_value = player_heal
func _damage():
    if inmunidad == true:
        if player_heal >0:
            player_heal = -1
            barra = player_heal
            inmunidad = false
        elif player_heal == 0:
         
            queue_free()```

    



  


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Este sitio es en español, asi que solo deja esa parte...

Los breakpoints (puntos de parada/interrupción/ruptura) son puntos en el código establecidos explícitamente por el desarrollador dónde la ejecución se para, permitiendo depurar el programa en ese momento concreto. En el caso de Godot, cuando estableces un punto de interrupción y el motor llega a él interrumpe el juego, dándote la oportunidad de usar las herramientas de depuracion para, por ejemplo, ver el valor de una variable en ese instante:

Los puntos de interrupción se establecen gráficamente haciendo click izquierdo a la izquierda del número de linea en cualquier linea de código en el editor:

Lo más seguro es que hayas creado uno inadvertidamente, si pulsas en el botón Continuar de la barra de herramientas del rastreador de pila, como se ve en la primera imagen, o el botón de pausa del proyecto, arriba a la derecha de la interfaz, el motor pasará de ese punto de interrupción y el juego continuará su ejecución normalmente.
Los puedes eliminar haciendo click en el mismo sitio, sobre el punto rojo, o puedes eliminarlos todos con el atajo de teclado Ctrl + Shift + F9 (si no has cambiado los atajos por defecto).
